# Showing the coordinates on a plot in TraditionalForm

Tags: graphics, traditional-form

I just want to show the coordinates `(Log[y/x],Log[x/y])` of a point on a Graphics object, but `TraditionalForm` fails to convert it, because `(Log[y/x],Log[x/y])` is not a valid expression in Mathematica. How can I fix it?

**Update**

Junho's comment technically solved my problem.

Input:

```
Graphics[{Text@ TraditionalForm[Row[{"(", Log[x/y], ",", Log[1 + y/x], ")"}]]}]
```

Output:

[image: ugly output]

But it looks really ugly, doesn't it? How can I make the outer paranthises larger and probably change the font to make it prettier?

Comment: `Row[{"(", Log[y/x], ", ", Log[x/y], ")"}] // TraditionalForm`

Comment: @JunhoLee: Thanks Junho. Your comment somehow solved the problem. See my update please.

Answer (score 2):

```
MatrixForm[{Log[x/y], ",", Log[1 + y/x]}, 
  TableDirections->Row, TableSpacing->0.3] // TraditionalForm
```

The spacing around the comma is not perfect but the parentheses look good.

Answer (score 1):

```
PrettyPoint /: MakeBoxes[PrettyPoint[e___], TraditionalForm] := 
  With[{mb = MakeBoxes[#, TraditionalForm] & /@ {e}},
   RowBox[{"(", Sequence @@ Riffle[mb, ","], ")"}]
  ]

PrettyPoint[Log[x/y], Log[1 + y/x]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ToString[{Log[x/y], Log[1 + y/x]},
 TraditionalForm]
```

[image]